# Find an algorithm to sort an array given its status after sorting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

> Let *A* be an array with *n* elements. *A* is not sorted, nonetheless, after sorting the array, the difference between any two adjacent elements would be either *k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub> or k<sub>3</sub>*.
>
> **It should be noted that *k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub> and k<sub>3</sub>* are not given, and all of them are *natural!***
>
> For example, given the array:
>
> ```
> A = { 25, 7, 5, 9, 32, 23, 14, 21}
> ```
>
> After sorting the array, we would get -
>
> ```
> A = { 5, 7, 9, 14, 21, 23, 25, 32}
> ```
>
> The difference between the first pair (5, 7) is 2; so *k<sub>1</sub>*=2, the difference between the third pair (9,14) is 5, so *k<sub>2</sub>*=5, whereas the difference between the fourth pair (14, 21) is 7, so *k<sub>3</sub>*=7. The difference between other adjacent pairs is also 2, 5 and 7.
>
> The algorithm for sorting the array should be as best as possible (obviously below *O(nlogn)*).

I managed to answer a similar question where the difference between any two adjacent elements was either *k, 2k or 3k*, where *k* is real. But I couldn't find an appropriate algorithm following a similar method, by finding *k*, dividing by it and doing bucket sort.

By finding the minimum and second minimum we can find one of the *k*'s. But *k* could be *n<sup>2</sup>* — so finding the maximum does not help either... I am really lost!

**Disclaimer:** This question has been asked before, but no answer was given to the problem, and the question was not easy to understand.

Comment: What do you want to do if the input doesn't meet the constraints, i.e. there are more than 3 different differences once the array is sorted.

Comment: The given array should always fulfill the characteristic written above.

Comment: *What is* the question here?  You don't appear to be being asked to write a sorting algorithm.

Comment: To find an algorithm that sorts the array (probably O(n))

Comment: If I understand correctly, we cannot assume, as in your example, that we can get k1, k2 and k3 by simply getting the 4 lowest elements

Comment: Yes, since the first and second pairs yield the same result (k1)

Comment: There are different definitions of *natural*. Does yours include or exclude 0?

Comment: Without the zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `O(n)` that only doesn't *look* efficient.

The idea is simple.  Given the minimum element and a list of values for `k`, you construct the biggest sorted set with the values of `k` that you already have found, find the smallest missing thing not in the set, and find a new value of `k`.  If there are `K` values of `k`, this operation is `O((1+K) * n)`.

Repeating this `K` times is therefore `O((1+K)^2 * n)`.

In our case `K` is constant, so we get `O(n)`.

Here it is in Python.

```
def special_sort (array):
    # special cases first.
    if 0 == len(array):
        return array
    elif 1 == len(array):
        return array
    elif 2 == len(array):
        return [min(array), max(array)]

    min_value = min(array)
    values_of_k = []
    leftovers = array

    while len(leftovers):
        values_of_k = sorted(values_of_k)
        values = set(array)
        sorted_array = [min_value]
        values.remove(min_value)
        found = True
        while found:
            found = False
            for k in values_of_k:
                if sorted_array[-1] + k in values:
                    found = True
                    sorted_array.append(sorted_array[-1] + k)
                    values.remove(sorted_array[-1])
                    break

        leftovers = list(values)
        if 0 == len(leftovers):
            return sorted_array
        else:
            first_missing = min(leftovers)
            # Find the first element of the array less than that.
            i = -1
            while i+1 < len(sorted_array) and sorted_array[i+1] < first_missing:
                i = i+1
            values_of_k.append(first_missing - sorted_array[i])

print(special_sort([25, 7, 5, 9, 32, 23, 14, 21]))
```

Comment: I haven't learned Python. But based on your explanation, I fail to see why this algorithm's time complexity is related to the number of different values of K.

Comment: By scanning the currently constructed array {current min+ current k, ....., maximum} and checking whether each element exists in the actual array takes O(n^2). Am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Comment: @KamalKhalaily The checks for existence in the set `values` are all hash lookups and therefore `O(1)`.  Scanning the currently constructed array is the `O(K)` term.  But that is OK, because `K` here never exceeds 3.

Comment: Hmmm apparently I am not catching up :( We have just learned hashing and the question is not supposed to include hashing (just sorting) but could be solved with hashing. Could you please elaborate with the algorithm, no need to write a code. :)

Comment: @KamalKhalaily I already explained it.  What you do is take a list of values of `k`, construct a sorted list of everything you can get to from the minimum element with your values of `k`, find the first thing not on the list, find out what new value of `k` you had been missing, then try again.  When you are able to generate the whole list in sorted order from your values of `k`, then you have all the values of `k` and (more importantly) the sorted list.

Comment: Each pass takes time `O(n (K+1))` and you need `K+1` passes.  Which makes it quadratic for a random list of numbers.  But if `K` is bounded (in this case by 3), it becomes `O(n)`.